# Formatting on the Trilogy

Tags: discussion, support, markdown

I'm curious about how different formatting works in the Trilogy sites. Especially the font size.  how does one make fonts larger or smaller than the standard size? I understand the other basic stuff, like bold or italics, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the formatting info is in `/editing-help`

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

as for what HTML is allowed see:

[What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user)

Comment: you must feel like a broken record sometimes `:p`